# Movie ending with an alien stabbing the passengers with spiked tentacles

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find this movie but I only remember the end of it. It was set on a plane and one of the doors opens and in comes this alien and it uses tentacles with spikes to kill the passengers via stabbing in the forehead so that little worm like things can enter the body through the hole. That is about all I remember.

Comment: Can you give any details about when you saw it and where (HBO, movie theatre.. etc?) and roughly when it was made?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Google-searching "alien tentacles on a plane" produced primarily erotica. but there was a movie called Altitude which featured huge tentacles attacking a moving aircraft.